# Using a one-time pad with a block cipher

Tags: block-cipher, one-time-pad, xor

The one-time pad is often described with a [simple XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).

This is nice for showing the theoretical strengths of the one-time pad, but not so great in real-world scenarios where key reuse is a danger.

So, is it feasible to use an n-bit block cipher with an n-bit key to replace the XOR operation (which itself is a 1-bit block cipher with a 1-bit key)?

So the encryption operation becomes

```
for each pBlock is n bits of plaintext
     take kBlock as the corresponding n bits of the key
     encrypt pBlock with kBlock as key using the block cipher and the result is cBlock
     append cBlock to the ciphertext
```

Decryption is the same.

Am I correct that this will make it more resistant (but not fully) to key reuse and known plaintext attacks than using the simple XOR? Or did I add a big vulnerability into the scheme?

Comment: Congratulations, you have discovered block cipher modes of operation. :)

Comment: @fkraiem they are hardly one time pads though at best those are a stream cipher, All those do is add a bit of entropy to avoid repeats.

Comment: Then please describe more precisely what you mean in your question. A one-time pad, as properly defined, does not use a block cipher, so the obvious answer to the question of whether you can "use a one-time pad with a block cipher" is no.

Comment: @fkraiem Ah I see where people got mistaken; I meant using a key as large as the plain text (like happens with one time pad)

Comment: By its list view, if I'm interpreting [this](https://oeis.org/A040082) correctly, the the possibilities for 2-bit blocks are all "equivalent" to the trivial ones (bitwise and [mod 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)), but there are lots of inequivalent possibilities for 3-bit blocks. ​ ​

Comment: I do not understand this step: "take kBlock as the corresponding n bits of the key". Can you explain it clearly?

Answer (score 3):

Well, no.

What you are describing is ECB mode of operation. ECB mode of operation is insecure as repeats of plaintext blocks leads to repeats of ciphertext blocks. This is a leak of information so it breaks confidentiality. So even if you would leak *less* information because of key reuse, you would still leak information if it happens.

Furthermore it is possible to find out if a key is (likely) correct by validating a ciphertext block against partial information within plaintext blocks. To that breaks the perfect secrecy provided by a One Time Pad.

---

I'll try and explain that last section further.

Note that there aren't $2^n$ possible permutations, there are $2^n!$ possible permutations. To be perfectly secure you should allow each one of them (with the same probability, no less).

That would mean that for any sensible $n$ the key size would grow out of proportion. Furthermore, you would have to have a cipher that would map all those keys to exactly one permutation, something that is not true for usual block ciphers.

So even if you have a key of n bits with m < n bits of known plaintext then it is likely that you can tell with a probability higher than $0.5$ if it is the correct one or not, breaking perfect secrecy for the remaining n - m bits.

Comment: I think the OP is not asking for "classic" ECB mode (encrypt each block by itself with the same key), but rather a variation of ECB mode where you use a different ( / random) key for each block you encrypt.

Comment: @SEJPM What do you think about it after the adjustment?

Comment: As long as there are no collisions in the block cipher (there is no plain/cipher block pair that have multiple possible keys) and per-block key size is equal or larger than block size then perfect secrecy is preserved assuming no key reuse.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: You are correct, but the question stipulates that no key reuse cannot be assumed.

Comment: Besides, in general you would expect a key to select a unique permutation. But permutations may still share plantext : ciphertext mappings. So your assumption may not hold.

Answer (score 1):

I think Maarten Bodewes' last comment is crucial. Even with uniformly chosen keys, since a random permutation on $\{0,1\}^n$ has roughly $2^n/e$ fixed points, the "block OTP" property will be lost relatively quickly, regardless of key reuse.